# AWS pem for ssh

Tags: ssh, aws

**Scenario:**  AWS Ubunutu instance - ssh connectiviy.

**Objective:**  Understand how the AWS pem file authorizes ssh connections.

**Background:**  I have created an ssh key pair using `ssh-keygen` and uploaded the public key to the `authorized_keys` file on my ubuntu instance. This connection works.  I also generated a `.pem` key in the console and downloaded it.  I gave it the recommmended `chmod 400` permissions and can connect using `ssh -i file.pem user@instance`.

**Point of Interest:**  Why is the public equivalent to the private `.pem` not in `authorized_keys` ***OR*** How does this really work?

Thanks